# How to pyUSB inside Processing's python mode

Tags: python, processing, pyusb

I am programming inside Processing.py and need to use pyUSB. I placed the downloaded files of pyUSB in the sketch folder and then run in the sketch

```
    import usb.core
    import usb.util
    import usb.control
```

Which runs successfully, however when I try to initialize the device I'm trying to communicate with, I get the error "No module named util" on the command below

```
   device = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_ID,
                               idProduct=PRODUCT_ID)
```

I don't know whether pyUSB is installed successfully. If anyone has installed this before please comment.

Comment: "installing' the package is different than downloading and importing locally. Did you run the `setup.py` file from the downloaded files in pyUSB? Checking the location of those modules with `print usb.util.__file__`. For them to be "installed" for python globally you'll either need to run the `setup.py` you downloaded, or `pip install pyusb`.

Answer (score 0):

Python Mode for Processing cannot use any Python libraries that depend on native code, such as pyUSB.